# Converting query from Microsoft SQL to Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

The following Microsoft SQL query compares two date fields of a table and returns those records for which the difference in minutes is greater than 5.

```
SELECT  t.Id, t.date1, t.date2,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.date1 , t.date2) AS Mtime 
FROM table1 t 
WHERE 
DATEDIFF(MINUTE,t.date1, t.date2) > 5
```

I have no idea how to write this with ORACLE. I've searched for solution and the closest I came to was :

```
SELECT  t.date1, t.date2,
    (t.date1 - t.date2) * 1440 AS Mtime 
FROM table1 t 
WHERE 

    (t.date1 -t.date2) * 1440 > 5
```

which gives me the error `inconsistent datatypes: expected INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND got NUMBER`

Does anyone know how to write this query with ORACLE ?

Comment: if you use the SQL Developer migration assistant, it makes a UTILS package available - one of the functions it comes with is an Oracle equivalent for DATEDIFF()

Comment: what are the data types of your table?  That sql you posted should have worked for date fields

Comment: the type is TimeStamp(4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the difference.  Just add the interval:

```
WHERE t.DeliveryDate >= t.Deadline + interval '5' minute
```

Or:

```
WHERE t.DeliveryDate >= t.Deadline + 5 / (24 * 60)
```

The equivalent in SQL Server is:

```
WHERE t.DeliveryDate >= DATEADD(minute, 5, t.Deadline)
```

This is a good habit.  If one of the values is a constant, then the use of a function (`-` or `datediff()`) prevents the use of an index.

Comment: Thanks, that is working. `WHERE t.DeliveryDate >= t.Deadline + 5 / (25 * 60)`

Comment: Why `25 * 60`? Shouldn't it be `24 * 60` or `1440`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
SELECT  t.Id, t.date1, t.date2,
(CAST(t.date1 AS DATE)-CAST(t.date2 AS DATE)) * 1440 AS Mtime FROM table1 t where (CAST(t.date1 AS DATE)-CAST(t.date2 AS DATE)) * 1440 > 5
```

Comment: `(t.date1 -t.date2) > 5` how it will compare with 5 minutes and your answer is not even correct is about datetime not date

Comment: It is actually the TIMESTAMP(4) type.

Comment: Thanks @JayShankarGupta that was my bad.